# Cannot modify a value type return value of `UnityEngine.Transform.position'

Tags: unity-game-engine

I would like to make it so that the camera zooms in a bit when the player aims with the gun.

The camera is parented to the player gameobject.

I have tried FieldOfView, and it works, but that is not what I need. 
Instead, I just want to really zoom in (=change the camera position's z value).

When I used FieldOfView, I used this code:

```
private IEnumerator LerpFoV(float fov)
{
    // lerping a value in this way may take quite some time to reach the exact target value, so we will just stop lerping when the difference is small enough, i.e 0.05
    float dif = Mathf.Abs(camera.fieldOfView - fov);

    while (dif > 0.05)
    {
        camera.fieldOfView = Mathf.Lerp(camera.fieldOfView, fov, 0.1f);
        // update the difference
        dif = Mathf.Abs(camera.fieldOfView - fov);
        yield return 0;
    }
    camera.fieldOfView = fov;
    yield return 0;
}
```

Could anybody tell me how to do the same with position z?

I guess it's not as complicated as I think, but this code doesn't work:

```
private IEnumerator LerpZPosition(float zValue)
{
    float dif = Mathf.Abs(camera.transform.position.z - zValue);

    while (dif > 0.05)
    {
        camera.transform.position.z = Mathf.Lerp(camera.transform.position.z, zValue, 0.1f);
        // update the difference
        dif = Mathf.Abs(camera.transform.position.z - zValue);
        yield return 0;
    }
    camera.transform.position.z = zValue;
    yield return 0;
}
```

The compiler tells me "Cannot modify a value type return value of `UnityEngine.Transform.position'. Consider storing the value in a temporary variable".

Can anybody tell me how to do that correctly?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I got it:

It is not possible to change camera.transform.position.x|y|z directly but instead you have to create a new Vector3 object.

So the solution would look like this:

```
private IEnumerator LerpZPosition(float zValue)
{
    float dif = Mathf.Abs(camera.transform.position.z - zValue);

    while (dif > 0.05)
    {
        float fLerp = Mathf.Lerp(camera.transform.position.z, zValue, 0.1f);
        Debug.Log("fLerp: " + fLerp.ToString());
        Vector3 v = new Vector3(camera.transform.position.x, camera.transform.position.y, fLerp);
        camera.transform.position = v;
        dif = Mathf.Abs(camera.transform.position.z - zValue);
        yield return 0;
    }
    camera.transform.position = new Vector3(camera.transform.position.x, camera.transform.position.y, zValue);
    yield return 0;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't help people by just pasting the answer like this. Could you please update your answer by explaning that it is not possible to change `camera.transform.position.x|y|z` directly but instead you have to create a new `Vector3` object. Thanks.

Comment: FWIW, its because `Vector3`is a struct, not a class.

Comment: @MadJlzz I added this info.